# why tablayout scroll up?

Tags: android, xml, android-tablayout

i'm trying to create app with 2 `tablayout` i follow some steps and every things works fine but i have this problem with `Tablayout` show me big space between `Toolbar` and `tablayout` like this photo when i scroll up tablyout Space disappears i want to remove this space

[image]

when i scroll up :

[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#ffffff">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Style.xml :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you also post your base theme from `Style.xml` - The empty space is probably second Toolbar. One is created by your theme and one you are adding yourself in layout.

Comment: @Sharj

`<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>`

Comment: i update my post

Comment: you are adding TabLayout in AppBarLayout so it scrolling.

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Comment: @Pavan how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

In your case the extra space is an toolbar in your xml on above tab layout and you are using theme

```
"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

which become causing two actionbar here, if you dont using toolbar just remove it

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#ffffff">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this will be your final xml after removing toolbar,
else you want toolbar then set the them which dont have actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Problem: I didn't see your Manifest file but it looks like you have one default `Toolbar` coming from your `Theme` and one you are setting yourself. To fix it, you can remove default Toolbar and use the one you added.

To fix this follow these steps.

Step 1: Add `NoActionBar` style to your Style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Step 2: Set `AppTheme.NoActionBar` to your Activity in Manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Now your Activity will not have a system Toolbar. You can add your own `Toolbar` customise it as you want.

Step 3: Set your layout `Toolbar` as default `Toolbar` inside your `Activity`.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Now you can use this `Toolbar`:

```
setTitle("Some Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is the second toolbar which is written by you in appbarlayout. First toolbar is by default toolbar.

you can remove extra space which is a toolbar by writing below code in your style.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Instead of

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Or

you can modify your appbarlayout code like below. You have just remove the toolbar from appbarlayout.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
               android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
               android:id="@+id/tabs"
               android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
               app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"
               app:tabGravity="fill"
               app:tabMode="fixed"
               app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
               android:elevation="10dp"/> 
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```